# Update a SQL Server table from a CTE and Case statement

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, common-table-expression

I have this code:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        LTRIM(RTRIM([EMP_ID])) AS empID
    FROM 
        [SAMPLE].[dbo].[segments]
)
SELECT
    (CASE WHEN LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(EMPID))) = 5 
             THEN RIGHT(('100' + EMPID), 8)
          WHEN LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(EMPID))) = 6 
             THEN RIGHT(('10' + EMPID), 8)
          WHEN LEN(EMPID) = 7 
             THEN RIGHT('10' + (LEFT(LTRIM(EMPID), 6)), 8)
          ELSE empID
     END) EMP_ID
FROM CTE
```

What I want to do is use the above state to update my `emp_id` column to the new 8 digit ids. Running the script returns the IDs correctly now I just need to update the table.

I tried the following and all it did was made all the IDs the same

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT 
        LTRIM(RTRIM([EMP_ID])) AS empID
    FROM 
        [SAMPLE].[dbo].[segments]
)
UPDATE segments
SET EMP_ID = (case when len(ltrim(rtrim(EMPID))) = 5 then right(('100' + EMPID),8 )
        when len(ltrim(rtrim(EMPID))) = 6 then right(('10' + EMPID),8 )
        when len(EMPID) = 7 then right('10'+(left(ltrim(EMPID),6)),8)
      else empID
      end) 
FROM CTE
```

What is the correct `UPDATE` statement to use for this?

Comment: Why not just use simple update?  Why the CTE?

Comment: Do  any EmpIDs contain non-numeric characters?

Comment: Oh, and when you've already checked the length of a string is 5 characters and you prepend 3,  _you don't need to trim the string back down to 8 again_. Same for 6 and 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without CTE you can try

```
UPDATE segments
SET EMP_ID = (case when len(ltrim(rtrim(EMP_ID))) = 5 then right(('100' + EMP_ID),8 )
    when len(ltrim(rtrim(EMP_ID))) = 6 then right(('10' + EMP_ID),8 )
    when len(EMP_ID) = 7 then right('10'+(left(ltrim(EMP_ID),6)),8)
  else emp_ID
  end)
```

OR if you want to use CTE you can try

```
With CTE
As 
(
SELECT ltrim(rtrim([EMP_ID])) as empIDTrim
, Emp_ID

FROM [SAMPLE].[dbo].[segments]
)
UPDATE CTE
SET EMP_ID = (case when len(empIDTrim)= 5 
then right('100' + empIDTrim,8 )
    when len(empIDTrim)= 6 
then right('10' + empIDTrim ,8 )
    when len(empIDTrim) = 7 
  then right('10'+left(empIDTrim,6),8)
  else empIDTrim
  end)
```

Answer (score 1):

include the base column in the [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) and update the `cte` directly:

```
;with cte as (
  select 
      emp_id
    , empid = '1'+replicate('0',7-len(ltrim(rtrim([emp_id]))))+ltrim(rtrim(emp_id))
  from segments
  where len(ltrim(rtrim([emp_id]))) < 8
)

update cte set emp_id = empid;

select *
from segments;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/YKO33009

returns:

```
+----------+
|  emp_id  |
+----------+
| 88888888 |
| 17777777 |
| 10666666 |
| 10055555 |
| 10004444 |
| 10000333 |
| 10000022 |
| 10000001 |
+----------+
```

from this test setup:

```
create table segments (emp_id char(8))
insert into segments values 
 ('88888888')
,('7777777')
,('666666')
,('55555')
,('4444')
,('333')
,('22')
,('1');
```

Comment: Thanks SqlZim for the explanation and tip.  This also worked well. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If the left-most 5 or 6 characters of the trimmed emp_id are all numeric, you can do this:

```
UPDATE [SAMPLE].[dbo].[segments]
SET EMP_ID = cast(10000000 + cast(ltrim(rtrim( case when len(ltrim(rtrim(emp_id))) > 6 then left(ltrim(rtrim(emp_Id)),6) else ltrim(rtrim(emp_id)) end)) as int) as char(8))
```

You can make this further easier to understand if you do it in two steps:

```
UPDATE [SAMPLE].[dbo].[segments]
SET Emp_ID = rtrim(ltrim(Emp_ID))

UPDATE [SAMPLE].[dbo].[segments]
SET EMP_ID = cast(10000000 + cast(case when len(emp_id) > 6 then left(emp_Id,6) else emp_id end as int) as char(8))
```

Though I strongly suspect even this isn't necessary, and your EMP_ID values are already trimmed. It can possibly get simpler still if you know the 7-character scenario is also numeric.

Finally, I get really nervous about `UPDATE` queries with no `WHERE`. It's possible you really mean it this time... but it's still scary to run.

Comment: Thanks Joel Coehoorn, that also works well much appreciated.

Comment: Yes I get your point but this will be a one time deal - we are moving all EMP_IDs from 5,6,7 digits to 8 digits.  As a result any historic data that I have will need to be converted to the new 8 digits IDs.